# How to identify an Application as Single threaded or Multi threaded?

Tags: java

How can i know whether the Application i am developing is single threaded or multi threaded? 
For example is StackOverflow a multi threaded or single thread Application?

We all login into stackoverflow, does that mean... at the same time n users are trying to access stackoverflow login class... `checkLogin` Method?

So should we declare the checkLogin method `synchronized`?

Answer (score 2):

How can you possibly *not* know whether the application *you are developing* is multithreaded? You're the developer!

However in Java, unless you have completely managed to avoid using Thread.start(), Swing, AWT, RMI, garbage collection, a servlet container, etc etc etc, your application *is* multithreaded.

Answer (score 2):

StackOverflow is not a common (desktop) application, it's a web application.

Web applications run on some sort of application server, which is almost always a multi-threaded program.

Regarding synchronized methods, you only need to add synchronization if multiple threads executing the method at the same time could cause unexpected behavior. That usually - but not always - happens when the method modifies shared variables (a counter variable, for instance) or accesses some limited resource (a socket for example).

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether a common application is multithreaded by using a debuger like OllyDbg